# How can I append a new feature to all input data, with value "1"?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, append

my dataset is:

```
dataset = sklearn.datasets.load_diabetes()
```

Actually I think I have to add a column with value 1.

Comment: Can you provide more detail? Provide your code attempt so far, the error you are getting, the data as it is at the moment, the desired data output. Always have a proper go at a question before resulting to asking for help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood is that you will be building a model and you need to add a column of intercept.

If this is really the case, all you have to do is:

```
dataset['intercept']=1
```